# Parentheses in regular expression pattern when splitting a string

Tags: python, regex

I would like to know the reason behind the following behaviour:

```
>>> re.compile("(b)").split("abc")[1]
'b'
>>> re.compile("b").split("abc")[1]
'c'
```

I seems that when I add parentheses around the splitting pattern, re adds it into the split  array. But why? Is it something consistent, or simply an isolated feature of regular expressions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a feature of `re.split`, according to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.split):

> If capturing parentheses are used in pattern, then the text of all groups in the pattern are also returned as part of the resulting list.

In general, parenthesis denote capture groups and are used to extract certain parts of a string. Read more about [capture groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Answer (score 4):

In any regular expression, parentheses denote a capture group. Capture groups are typically used to extract values from the matched string (in conjunction with [`re.match`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.match) or [`re.search`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.search)). For details, refer to the [official documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) (search for `(...)`).

[`re.split`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.split) adds the matched groups in between the splitted values:

> If capturing parentheses are used in pattern, then the text of all groups in the pattern are also returned as part of the resulting list.